# Make Search Box Responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

How can I make this responsive? I want to change the width from px to %. But I don't get the same result. I want to maintain the size but I want it to be responsive.

```
.cf:before, .cf:after{content:"";display:table;}
.cf:after{clear:both;}
.cf{zoom:1;}

.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.form-wrapper input {
    width: 330px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;    
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}    

.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}   

.form-wrapper button:hover{     
    background: #e54040;
}   

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{   
    background: #c42f2f;    
}

.form-wrapper button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}

.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before{
    border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}    

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

There is nothing more I can say, so ill just add this text since it won't let me post this question because of too little words. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
 *, *:before, *:after{
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

    .cf:before, .cf:after{content:"";display:table;}
.cf:after{clear:both;}
.cf{zoom:1;}

.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.form-wrapper input {
    width: 310px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;    
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}    

.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}   

.form-wrapper button:hover{     
    background: #e54040;
}   

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{   
    background: #c42f2f;    
}

.form-wrapper button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}

.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before{
    border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}    

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .form-wrapper{
    width: 300px;
  }
  .form-wrapper input{
    width: 160px;
  }
}
```

```html
  <form class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use "max-width"  instead of width  it will make it responsive and also maintain the width you don't need to make it in "%"
    <pre>
    .form-wrapper {
        max-width: 450px;
    }
    .form-wrapper input {
        max-width: 330px;
    }

    </pre>
```